# Inserting image into jupyter notebook using JavaScript

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter

My goal is to show a logo everytime I open my a notebook with jupyter. The way I went about this was to create a

- custom.js
- custom.css

file inside .jupyter/custom/ .

custom.js:

```
var html_outlie = `
<div id="test-container" class="container">

    <div id="test-logo">
        <img src="<what_location??>/logo.png"></img>
    </div>

</div>
`

jQuery("#notebook_panel").prepend(html_outlie)
```

and my custom.css has:

```
#test-container {
    background-color: white;
    padding: 50px 0;
}


#test-logo {
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
```

The problem is, depending on which path I start the notebook, the logo will not show. How can I use an absolute path so that no matter where I start my notebook, the logo will always show?

The next step would be that everyone working on their own computer, and uses the same customizations, will see the logo.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot out of the box make requests to absolute paths for security reasons.

What you are actually trying to do is a [write a server extension with custom handlers](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extending/handlers.html), and one that can serve the logo file under a relative url of your choice.

This extension will have complete access to the local filesystem and do whatever it wants.

You may have to handle "base_url" on the javascript side, in case the notebook is deployed on JupyterHub behind a prefix, but that's not necessary for most users, nor when developping.